# regex_replace of Ansible

Tags: regex, ansible

I would like to change for "radius-server dead-criteria time 10 tries 3" config to 5 times from ansible

I create the below script but it doesn't work as I expected.

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  vars:
    ansible_network_os: ios
    ansible_connection: network_cli

  tasks:
    - name: show running-config
      ios_command:
        commands:
          - show running-config
      register: result
    - name: Radius server setting
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        new_radius_server_config: "{{ result.stdout_lines | regex_findall('radius-server dead-criteria time [0-9]{1,2} tries [1-4]{1}') | regex_replace('tries [1-4]{1}$', 'tries 5') }}"
    - name: New radius server setting
      debug:
        msg: "{{ result }}"
    - name: New radius server setting
      debug:
        msg: "{{ new_radius_server_config }}"
```

I expect to put 'new_radius_server_config' to
"radius-server dead-criteria time 10 tries 5"
but not work...

I suppose '$' means end of sentence but it doesn't work as I expected.

could you provide your advice?

Answer (score 0):

The $ character indeed represents the end of the line, but it does not match the end of the sentence in this context. Try this it may work not sure if it works let me know.

```
config: "radius-server dead-criteria time 10 tries 3"

- name: Radius server setting
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    new_radius_server_config: "{{ config | regex_replace('tries [1-4]{1}$', 'tries 5') }}"

- name: New radius server setting
  debug:
    msg: "{{ new_radius_server_config }}"
```

Comment: but the code was summarized and the actual code doesn't work.

Comment: the code is updated.

Comment: if I remove '$' it works but I would like to verify if it is end of line.

Comment: I have solved the issue as I use the below code.
`new_radius_server_config: "{{ result.stdout | regex_findall('radius-server dead-criteria time [0-9]{1,2} tries [1-4]{1}\\\\n') | regex_replace(' [1-4]{1}\\\\', ' 5') }}"`
$ didn't work well but we can find end of line with '\\\\n'